# How to send filter params in wp-api with angular resource?

Tags: wordpress, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to "dynamically" add filter[something] eg. category_name, cat etc with an angular resource.

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?filter[filter]=angular.var.here
```

but without hardcoding the filters.. so I can pass various types of filters without changing the base resource.

Comment: looking also urgently for a solution :-|

Answer (score 1):

If your Category is changed by a button in you main html file, you can try to get the newCategory value adding this inside your controller app:

```
$scope.$watch('currentCategory', function(newCategory){
    $scope.watchCategory = newCategory;


  $http.get('/wp-json/posts?filter[filter]=' + newCategory)
```